# Pandas pivot_table do not comply with values order

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have an issue with pandas pivot_table.

Sometimes, the order of the columns specified on "values" list does not match

```
In [11]: p = pivot_table(df, values=["x","y"], cols=["month"], 
                             rows="name", aggfunc=np.sum)
```

i get the wrong order (y,x) instead of (x,y)

```
Out[12]:
        y           x
month   1   2   3   1   2   3
name
a       1 NaN   7   2 NaN   8
b       3 NaN   9   4 NaN  10
c     NaN   5 NaN NaN   6 NaN
```

Is there something i don't do well ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), `values` should take the name of a single column, not an iterable.

> values : column to aggregate, optional

Comment: Values can take an iterable even if the documentation do not detail it. The problem is that the column order is not fulllfiled

Comment: What happens when you use the `columns` argument instead?